# Redirect to a pdf after submitting a form

Tags: php

On my website, I have a simple form which users fill in with their data. After clicking submit, their data is saved in the database and then I want the page to redirect to a pdf, which will start downloading straight away.

Here is the section of relevant PHP code:

```
<?php header('Location: http://website.com/html/India_Report_June_2013.pdf'); ?>
```

However, after clicking submit, the page directs to the products page of my website, and no download. But the data does get inserted into the database. Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: I think that stackoverlow is not the rigth place for this type of question. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Sounds like you've got another redirect in your code before that one.

Comment: Or another redirect overwriting this one. Check network infos with developer tools (e.g. FireBug / Chrome DevTools).

Comment: try adding an `exit;` right after the `header()` line

Comment: exit; doesnt work, and the insert.php file is quite short so definately no other redirects in that page. Tried looking at the network info, but not entirely sure what i should be looking of. For some reason, when i enter 'www.website.com/html/India_Report_June_2013.pdf' into the browser directly, it still brings up the product page. Is there any code i can write in the insert.php file to stop this from happening?